# Why are true and false the only truth values used in mathematics?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, truth

Why do we use only true and false? It is possible to have many states in-between in fuzzy logic and other many-valued logics.

If we assign numbers to true and false, such as 1 and 0 respectively, what would be the logical interpreation of -1, i, j or k (with i,j,k as [defined for quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion))?  Is there any reason for this dichotomy? What type of statement would have these truth values if such a statement existed?

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy SE. This question is not completely clear in what you're asking and could benefit from some clarification. The simple answer is that true and false have specific meanings in certain contexts which would not admit other concepts; remember that mathematics and philosophy both add value to human thought primarily through what they *dis*allow, not what they allow. Order is in effect the containment of thought to specific concepts deemed to be valid as a model within the universe that also seems to constrain events to a given valid set we interpret as order.

Comment: Maybe not; see [Three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) and [Many-Valued Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-manyvalued/).

Comment: The ides that there are TRUE statement is very deeply grounded in our language, and also bivalence, i.e. the fact that what is not TRUE is FALSE. But, at the same time, the [Vagueness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/vagueness/) phenomenon is widely present in our language an daily life, and this does not fit well with bivalence.

Comment: **0** and **1** in logic are not *numbers* but [Boolean values](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boolalg-math/).

Comment: The question is kind of like asking "Why are there only 10 digits?". Well, in the **decimal** system there is 10, because **that is what defines it as a decimal system**!. But in others, there are more or less digits. So short answer: the question is faulty, there is not at all **only** "true" and "false"; how many values there are depends entirely depends on what system you use. If you are not happy with using systems that are true/false binary, then use one that is not binary.

Comment: I'd suppose the more "philosopher's" type answer (since you're asking it on the Philosophy Stack Exchange) is that if "truth" is taken as the interval [0, 1] and "zero truth" means "total falsehood" and "1 truth" means "total truth" to have a truth value "less than 0" (i.e "-1 truth") would mean it would have to somehow be "even falser than absolutely/completely false" - so what would that mean? It's a bit like asking "what's north of the North Pole"? or "what does it mean to move more slowly than sitting absolutely still?"

Comment: There is also meaningless and undecidable, giving four possible values.

Comment: @TimBII I think the question is clear, the question asks why mathematics has chosen for a two-valued logic system and whether 'other-valued' logic systems could be useful.

Comment: @Discretelizard if that's the case, then he's answered his own question by mentioning related many valued logics. Not all logic IS bivalent (although admittedly most is) and why bring in imaginary numbers at all? Seems like a lot of chaff in the way of what *could* be a clear question.

Comment: @TimBII How does this question answer the question _why_ two-valued logic is used? I mean, there _are_ valid reasons to prefer non two-valued logics for certain cases, fuzzy logic has had practical uses, for instance.

Comment: @Discretelizard I actually don't disagree with you about it being preferable in many cases to have bivalent logic; what I was saying above is that the title refers to there *only* being true and false, and then the body of the question not only shows that not to be the case, but then wants to know why the former is the case again, while asking if the latter can be a good idea. The question is actually a good one, but is written (IMHO) in a confusing manner. Your answer to it reflects a good understanding of the intent, but that doesn't mean the question's wording can't be improved.

Comment: @TimBII Ah, I see what you mean. Well, then lets see if editing helps.

Comment: They are not. Division by zero is an example of value '2' = Undetermined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question whether we could have a logical system that can be represented with complex numbers raise an interesting point: Are the logical systems where multiple dimensions are useful?

The answer turns out to be yes. Consider the [multidimensional logic](http://cogprints.org/1479/1/mdl.html)  of Carlos Gershenson.

Here, each logical variable is a pair from the 'square' [0,1] x [0,1]. The reason that a 2-dimensional representation is chosen is such that we can assign a truth value to even paradoxical statements such as "This phrase is false." The basic idea is that if for the pair (x,y) we have x+y=1, then this is considered a non-paradoxical value within fuzzy logic<sup>1</sup>. Otherwise, the truth value is paradoxical, but can still be represented and computed with. (for more information, see the link provided)

---

But let me answer your actual question. One of the main reasons that most of mathematics uses a two-valued logical system is that most of mathematics is concerned with proving something *either* true or false. Nothing else. Hence, as mathematicians only wish to speak about two logical values for their statements, a two-valued logical system is the simplest system that allows them to do that.

<sub>1: Here we see a parallel with the 'imaginary numbers', they were introduced in Cardano's formula as an 'algebraic trick' to have some 'nonsense' in the middle of a derivation, but a correct result at the end)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Actually in some logics, specifically in continuous model theory, we can consider the interval [0,1] instead of the usual proposition set {0,1} and take 0 as indicating the truth value and 1 as the false value because sup[0,1]=1 and inf[0,1]=0. Also, while there are many complex number values there is only one number whose square is -1, and that is i.

The reason for this dichotomy is because logic is normally looked at algebraically instead of geometrically, thus forcing us to consider how to construct truth-value systems.

As for what type of statement would have truth value of i and negative one, well it would definitely have to be mathematical formalizations of some type of dialectical logic that relies heavily upon idempotents(mathematical objects whose iterations equals itself) to build its truth-value system. I do not know about the specifics since such a system is not yet known/proved to exist yet.

Comment: What's the square of `-i`?

Comment: (-i)^2=(-1*i)^2=(-1)^2*(i)^2=1*(i)^2=i^2=-1. The square of -i is also -1.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of stochastics relies on generalization the two discrete truth-values 0 and 1 to the continuous interval [0,1] of probabilities, i.e. all real numbers between 0 and 1 are possibile probabilities. Choosing "0" and "1" as two distinguished truth values is a suitable convention - remember the dual system in computing. Probabilities have to satisfy certain axioms, e.g. for disjoint sets A and B of events

p(A union B)= p(A) + p(B)

Therefore one cannot choose quite arbitrary numbers for probabilities and truth values.

Comment: I'm not sure if stochastics is that relevant here. Even in stochastics, each event either occurs or doesn't. There are still only 2 truth values. The only thing that is on an interval is our _uncertainty_ of the event. Also, your axiom is wrong. Not only do the events need to be disjoint, they also need to _independent_.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the wrong axiom. - I consider probability a generalization of the two discrete truth values. Probability does not only capture our uncertainty of the event. In quantum mechanics probability often captures a property inherent to the event, independent from our knowledge.

Comment: "Probability does not only capture our uncertainty of the event". Nevertheless, there are only 2 truth values in mainstream stochastics. I don't think anyone's opinion on what stochastics _should be_ matters. Therefore, I think this answer is misleading at best.

Comment: What's wrong in your opinion with considering probability a generalization(!) of the two discrete truth values?

Comment: 1) This contradicts the interpretation(s) in mainstream stochastics. 2) The concept of a (probability) _measure_ is a very different mathematical object than a logical variable or operations on such variables. 3) The mainstream generalisation you want is known as 'fuzzy logic', see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic#Comparison_to_probability) for the differences between this and probability.

Comment: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-probability/ Probabilistic semantics thus replaces the valuations v : L→{0,1} of classical propositional logic with probability functions P : L→ ℝ, which take values in the real unit interval [0,1]. The classical truth values of true (1) and false (0) can thus be regarded as the endpoints of the unit interval [0,1], and likewise, valuations v : L→{0,1} can be regarded as degenerate probability functions P : L→ [0,1]. In this sense, classical logic is a special case of probability logic, ....

Comment: Yes, of course you can do that. This definition, however, contradicts modern stochastics. In modern stochastics, probability measures P are functions from a sigma algebra S of measurable events to the unit interval. There is no function over a 'propositional language'. That there apparently is another definition of 'probability' (there are many such!) within logic doesn't imply that stochastics, a field within mathematics, needs to be consistent with this interpretation! I still don't understand why you seem to be claiming that your own thoughts need to be accepted from within stochastics!

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, there isn't.

There are certainly theories that would admit a -1, or the range of integers, or an interval of reals, or an infinite vector space (the space of state matrices in quantum physics) as proper representations of some logical state.

But logic seeks a basis for thought.  It is looking for what can be seen as most basic.  And for most humans, that is a binary comparison.

Within that Boolean context, what behavior could i have?  First, you would have to decide how the math maps.  In Boole, addition means 'or' and multiplication means 'and'.  So in that world -1 = 1.  A truth value of i or -i then would have to be 'alternate units' in the algebraic sense, two things that are neither true nor false separately, but when both apply, they establish a true statement.

Then instead of there being exactly three such things, there would really be an infinity of them, and they may not be very useful.  But they might be fun to contrive.

Comment: I agree about equivalence. But suggest a different mapping for i; as something intrinsically contradictory but set in an undetermined way to take on one of the other truth values. This is by analogy with https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_field As you say, just contrivances, and this suggestion is just for fun.

Comment: @CriglCragl  But something intrinsically contradictory should not have a modulus of 1.  Because something with modulus 1 can never be zero. It needs to be somehow incomplete unless it is squared.  You could follow down Re(i) == 0, and have orthogonal truths.  But someone else already commented on multidimensional interpretations, and I didn't care for it.

Comment: @CriglCragl You may be interested in the multidimensional logic I refer to in my answer, as that assigns logical value to paradoxical statement. A value is considered 'non-paradoxical' only if the norm (L1 norm, not Euclidean) is 1 and hence can be seen as a fuzzy logic value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all other forms of logic (e.g. with 2+ values), should you ever really need them, can be simulated with ordinary mathematics based on good old-fashioned true-or-false logic.

Comment: This is a rather vague claim. I'm not sure if it is completely true. Even if it holds, the fact that we can 'simulate' other logics (whatever that means) doesn't mean other logics are useless. Sometimes, other logics are simply an easier way to describe or solve certain problems. This is one of the reasons why fuzzy logic has uses in practice.

Comment: Suppose you want to simulate 256-value logic. Then each "logical" operator could be represented by binary function on the the set of natural numbers less than 256.

Comment: Yes, but why would you?

Comment: @Discretelizard I can't think of any applications off hand, but I understand that 8-value logic can provide some processing efficiencies in computer chips. Of course, the same functionality could be made available using standard 2-value logic.

Comment: Perhaps I should be clearer. Why would you simulate some multi-valued logic with some numbers? Why not just use the multi-valued logic immediately.

Comment: With a two-value logic system, you should be able to handle all the other multi-value logic systems. One-size fits all.You really only need to learn one system.

Comment: That is like saying you don't need to know anything about math but set theory, because it can 'handle' complex analysis, measure theory etc. My point is that your 'mechanistic' view of wanting to 'construct' a logic system is irrelevant, because what matters is whether the system makes it easier for humans to reason with in certain situation. Often, it is easier to reason with some object A than B, even in the case where A and B are isomorphic.

Comment: Often is easier to reason about something using a proven and familiar system. And easier to communicate your results with others.